# Test that a object is of one or the other instance

Tags: php, phpunit

This sounds like such a simple problem and I am new to PHPUnit however I have looked through the documentation and I cannot seem to find out how to say:

```
assert($class instanceof MongoClient || $class instanceof Mongo);
```

That's in pseudo code but hopefully it makes sense.

The closest I found to it was: http://www.phpunit.de/manual/current/en/writing-tests-for-phpunit.html#writing-tests-for-phpunit.assertions.assertContainsOnlyInstancesOf

So I think this is not natively supported in PHPUnit. Is there a good workaround or do I need to do this myself?

Comment: What is wrong with what you already have there?

Comment: Well it doesn't use PHPUnit, is that a bad thing? Or is that perfectly fine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`assert` in PHPUnit just takes a boolean value.

What you have in the pseudo-code is perfectly fine.

Comment: Ah ok kool, I see it now I can just use `assertTrue` on it if I wanna :) thanks, noobie question there